# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request

Tags: php, soap

Hi I am getting this error from the eway token payment api integration.

SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request

While i run following code then Functions from soap

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

and function list is

```
array
  0 => string 'CreateCustomerResponse CreateCustomer(CreateCustomer $parameters)' (length=65)
  1 => string 'UpdateCustomerResponse UpdateCustomer(UpdateCustomer $parameters)' (length=65)
  2 => string 'QueryCustomerResponse QueryCustomer(QueryCustomer $parameters)' (length=62)
  3 => string 'QueryCustomerByReferenceResponse QueryCustomerByReference(QueryCustomerByReference $parameters)' (length=95)
  4 => string 'ProcessPaymentResponse ProcessPayment(ProcessPayment $parameters)' (length=65)
  5 => string 'ProcessPaymentWithCVNResponse ProcessPaymentWithCVN(ProcessPaymentWithCVN $parameters)' (length=86)
  6 => string 'ProcessPaymentWithBeagleResponse ProcessPaymentWithBeagle(ProcessPaymentWithBeagle $parameters)' (length=95)
  7 => string 'QueryPaymentResponse QueryPayment(QueryPayment $parameters)' (length=59)
  8 => string 'CreateCustomerResponse CreateCustomer(CreateCustomer $parameters)' (length=65)
  9 => string 'UpdateCustomerResponse UpdateCustomer(UpdateCustomer $parameters)' (length=65)
  10 => string 'QueryCustomerResponse QueryCustomer(QueryCustomer $parameters)' (length=62)
  11 => string 'QueryCustomerByReferenceResponse QueryCustomerByReference(QueryCustomerByReference $parameters)' (length=95)
  12 => string 'ProcessPaymentResponse ProcessPayment(ProcessPayment $parameters)' (length=65)
  13 => string 'ProcessPaymentWithCVNResponse ProcessPaymentWithCVN(ProcessPaymentWithCVN $parameters)' (length=86)
  14 => string 'ProcessPaymentWithBeagleResponse ProcessPaymentWithBeagle(ProcessPaymentWithBeagle $parameters)' (length=95)
  15 => string 'QueryPaymentResponse QueryPayment(QueryPayment $parameters)' (length=59)
```

and When i call the function like this

```
$client->CreateCustomer($customerinfo);
```

Then it gives error to me SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request.

The $customerinfo is array of all the data.

Comment: The SoapFault class exposes several undocumented properties, could you post their values? `$error->faultcode`, `$error->faultmessage`, `$error->detail` for starters.

Comment: 'faultstring' => string 'Bad Request' (length=11)
'faultcode' => string 'HTTP' (length=4)
'xdebug_message' => string SoapFault: Bad Request in D:\wamp\www\eway\newfile.php on line <i>194</i>

Comment: Well, those messages were slightly less informative than I hoped they'd be :) Could you please post whatever `$client->__getLastResponse()` returns after the exception?

Comment: $client->__getLastResponse() is null

Comment: @Jakub Here is the detail question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394612/soapfault-exception-http-bad-request-in-eway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to data you are passing in the `$parameters` array. Ensure your data is `SOAP` compliant, and your request follows the same. `HTTP 400` occurs , when SOAP processor is not able to understand the request.

Encoding plays a major role in data sending and receiving. If the payload has non-SOAP encoded parts, that may lead to such a situation. If you can log the request , in `CreateCustomer()`, you can validate the request.

Troubleshoot based on above said things, I hope you can resolve the problem. It will be also helpful if you can post your question a little more clear and elaborate

Comment: Hi Krishnanunni, here is the detail question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394612/soapfault-exception-http-bad-request-in-eway